# NSManagedObject won't be updated after saving with Magical Record

Tags: ios, objective-c, block, nsmanagedobject, magicalrecord

I have a `NSManagedObject` (File) with some properties and I wrote some code that downloads a file with `AFNetworking` based on the information in this `NSManagedObject` - the download works fine!
Now I want to change some MetaData in the `completion block` and save the changes to `CoreData` using `Magical Record`. This basically works, except I have to restart the App to get the new values of the `NSManagedObject` - And this is the problem. During one lifecycle I'm not able to get the updated `NSManagedObject`. I even tried to refetch the object...

I don't understand, why I would have to restart to App to get the updated information? Is there a `context` issue? I don't see it.

I get the File Object from the `defaultContext`:

```
NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = [NSManagedObjectContext MR_defaultContext];
NSFetchRequest *fetch = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
[fetch setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"File" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext]];
```

And here's my download method:

```
- (void)downloadFile:(File*)fileObject {

...

    completionBlock:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        [MagicalRecord saveWithBlockAndWait:^(NSManagedObjectContext *localContext) {
            File *localFile = [fileObject MR_inContext:localContext];
            localFile.downloadStatus_ = [NSNumber numberWithInt:DownloadStatusCompleted];
         }];

        NSLog(@"State: %@"fileObject.downloadStatus_);

    }

}
```

**Update**:
I changed the line and it worked. I'm puzzled. I would guess, that localContext should actually be the current context. Which should be the one the object's.

```
File *localFile = [fileObject MR_inContext:localContext];
```

to

```
File *localFile = [fileObject MR_inContext:[NSManagedObjectContext MR_defaultContext]];
```

Comment: When are you running your fetch? If you're blocking and waiting why do you use the local context? Have you considered using a fetched results controller?

Comment: The fetch takes place before the File is downloaded. As I understand MR one should use the localContext.

Comment: You said `I even tried to refetch the object...` - where did you try that?

Comment: after the NSLog statement (at that time, the property should be updated.

Comment: You should verify that `MR_inContext:` returns an instance in that context (as it can fail and return nil).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what happened and wanted to post the answer.

It turned out that a property of the NSManagedObject *fileObject was changed without saving it, in advance of calling the completionBlock! The StoreCoordinator tries to merge and save the changed property (within the completionBlock) - but this operation failed since the original object from the context was changed...